# Why does the Yamada-Watanabe Uniqueness Theorem for SDEs not hold in the multidimensional case?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the stochastic differential equation
$$ dX_t = b(t,X_t)\,dt + \sigma(t,X_t) \, dB_t, \quad t \geq 0. $$
where $b:[0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $\sigma: [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ are measurable and $B$ is a standard Brownian Motion in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

In dimension $n=1$, it is a well-known result by Yamada and Watanabe that for pathwise uniqueness, we do not need both $b$ and $\sigma$ to be uniformly Lipschitz continuous in the second variable (the usual condition in arbitrary dimensions), but it suffices for $b$ to be Lipschitz and $\sigma$ to only be Hölder-$\frac{1}{2}$-continuous. Actually, this is a special case (insert $\kappa(u) = L|u|$ and $\rho(u) = C|u|^{1/2}$ to recover it) of the slightly more general

> **Theorem.** Assume $\exists \gamma >0$ a constant and $\kappa, \rho:[0, \gamma] \to [0, \infty)$ with
> \begin{align}\kappa(0) = 0, \quad |b(t,x)-b(t,y)| &\leq \kappa(|x-y|), \\  | \sigma(t,x) - \sigma(t,y) | &\leq \rho(|x-y|) \end{align} for all $t \in [0, \infty), x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ with $ |x-y| \leq \gamma$.
>
> Assume $\rho$ and $\kappa$ are non-decreasing and strictly positive on $(0, \gamma]$, $\kappa$ is concave, and $$\int_0^{\gamma} \frac{du}{\kappa(u)} = \infty = \int_0^{\gamma} \frac{du}{\rho^2(u)}. $$
>
> Then for every initial distribution $\mu$, pathwise uniqueness of the SDE holds.

The theorem in this (and even more general) form can for example be found at the beginning of [Altay and Schmock](https://www.fam.tuwien.ac.at/%7Eschmock/notes/Yamada-Watanabe.pdf).

---

In general dimensions $n \geq 3$ ($n=2$ too by [Swart](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-communications-in-probability/volume-6/issue-none/A-2-Dimensional-SDE-Whose-Solutions-are-Not-Unique/10.1214/ECP.v6-1035.full)), it was proved by [Yamada and Watanabe](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-11/issue-3/On-the-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-stochastic-differential-equations-II/10.1215/kjm/1250523620.full) in their second(!) paper from 1971 that this is not true. In general, $\rho$ has to satisfy (some technical conditions and) $\int_0^{\gamma} \frac{u}{\rho(u)^2} du = \infty$, which again is nearly Lipschitz continuity. If not, so if $$\int_0^{\gamma} \frac{u}{\rho(u)^2} du < \infty$$ and $\rho$ is subadditive, then pathwise uniqueness (and also uniqueness in law) does not hold. This is fulfilled by $$\rho(u) = |u|^{\alpha}, \quad \alpha <1.$$

Now this raises the

> **Question.** Why does (essentially) Hölder-$\frac{1}{2}$ continuity not suffice in the multidimensional case?
>
> Sure, Yamada and Watanabe provide a counterexample, but for me it is not intuitively clear why it only works in $n \geq 2$ dimensions.
>
> Also, I thought that the Hölder-$\frac{1}{2}$ continuity in one dimension is essentially due to that of the driving Brownian Motion (locally for every $\beta < \frac{1}{2}$). Is that true, and why does this fail for $n \geq 2$?

Answer (score 1):

> Sure, Yamada and Watanabe provide a counterexample, but for me it is not intuitively clear why it only works in $n \geq 2$ dimensions.

I will go over their example for $n\geq 3$. (For $n=2$, they suggest using a similar example by further inserting $\log(1/\xi)$).

We go over the counterexample by Yamada-Watanabe in [On the uniqueness of solutions of stochastic differential equations II](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-11/issue-3/On-the-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-stochastic-differential-equations-II/10.1215/kjm/1250523620.full). Consider function $\rho:\mathbb{R}^{+}\to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ satisfying $\rho(0)=0$

$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\rho^{-2}(\xi)\xi d \xi<\infty\text{ and }\rho(\xi_1+\xi_2)\leq \rho(\xi_1)+\rho(\xi_2).$$

So their counterexample is quite generic because there are many such functions $\rho$.

Fix $n\geq 3$. Then we let for $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

$$\sigma_{i,j}(t,x):=\delta_{ij}\rho(|x|),i,j=1,...,n.$$

By the above subadditivity this implies
$$|\sigma_{i,j}(t,x)-\sigma_{i,j}(t,y)|\leq \rho(|x-y|).$$

The claim is that $$\left\{\begin{matrix}dx_{t}=\sigma(x_{t})dB_{t}\\x_{0}=0 \end{matrix}\right.$$

has multiple solutions. First it has the zero solution. But by the [Dubins-Schwartz](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/), we will obtain yet another nonzero solution.

Consider an independent Brownian motion $\beta_{s}$. We consider the time change

$$A_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t}\rho^{-2}(|\beta_{s}|)ds.$$

This defines a continuous functional: the density of $Y=|\beta_{s}|$ is [What's the expectation of square root of Chi-square variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059938/whats-the-expectation-of-square-root-of-chi-square-variable)

$$f_Y(\xi)=\frac{1}{s^{n/2}}\frac{\xi^{n-1} e^{-\xi^2/2s}}{2^{n/2-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\qquad \xi>0,$$

and so

$$E[A_{t}]=\omega_{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho^{-2}(\xi)\left[\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{(2\pi s)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{\xi^{2}}{2s}}ds\right] \xi^{n-1}d\xi.$$

The inner integral evaluates to

$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{(2\pi s)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{\xi^{2}}{2s}}ds=c\xi^{-(n-2)}\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{\xi^{2}}{2t})=c\xi^{-(n-2)}\int_{\frac{\xi^{2}}{2t}}^{\infty}y^{\frac{n}{2}-2}e^{-y}dy.$$

So we see in the second integral that we need $n\geq 3$ to get it to be finite (i.e. in n=3 we get

$$\int_{\frac{\xi^{2}}{2t}}^{\infty}y^{-1/2}e^{-y}dy$$

which is still finite even if $\frac{\xi^{2}}{2t}\approx 0$.) From here we proceed as in their proof to get boundedness

$$E[A_{t}]\leq c_{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho^{-2}(\xi) \xi d\xi<\infty.$$

So

$$B_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^{-1}(\beta_{A_{t}^{-1}})d\beta_{A_{t}^{-1}}$$

is a Brownian motion and $\beta_{A_{t}^{-1}}$ will be a nonzero solution of the above SDE (since $A_{t}^{-1}\neq 0$ to $t>0$).

> Why does Hölder-$(\frac{1}{2})^{-}$-continuity not suffice in the multidimensional case?

First to be clear there have been some extensions to Hölder-regular coefficients eg some highly cited works are

- [MULTIDIMENSIONAL YAMADA-WATANABE THEOREM AND ITS APPLICATIONS TO PARTICLE SYSTEMS](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article/54/2/021503/233148/Multidimensional-Yamada-Watanabe-theorem-and-its)
- [Strong solutions of SDES with singular drift and Sobolevdiffusion coefficient](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414905000797)

In Revuz-Yor in "The Case of Hölder Coefficients in Dimension One", they give some intuition on what is special about 1-d.

- They use that local time in 1-d is a uniformly continuous process. (So here we are touching the deeper phenomenon of Brownian motion being recurrent in 1d, neighboorhood-reccurent in 2d and transient in $n\geq 3$).
- They mention that even though ODEs with Hölder Coefficients can fail to have uniqueness eg. $y'=\sqrt{y}$ [Uniqueness of ODEs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950435/uniqueness-of-odes), here we can have uniqueness because we define SDEs and Itô-integrals in terms of the quadratic variation which we know is finite and so it relaxes the integrability constraints.

More recently we also had a notion of SDEs using Rough paths that helped defined stochastic integrals pathwise [Could someone explain rough path theory? More specifically, what is the higher ordered "area process" and what information is it giving us?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212111/could-someone-explain-rough-path-theory-more-specifically-what-is-the-higher-o).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! This really sheds some light onto the counterexample. Do you also know something about the intuition of why Hölder-$\frac{1}{2}$ suffices in 1 dimension but not more? (So the third paragraph of the question)

Comment: @Alex well the above $\rho$ in the counterexample can be taken to be Hölder too. So I am not sure what you are asking. Yes in d=1 one can work with Hölder-coefficients and in higher dimensions the above provides a counterexample for n\geq 3 (for n=2 you can adjust their example as they mention).

Comment: Then please excuse my unclear phrasing :) I meant now just the intuitive side in gerenal, not the counterexample. Like, I thought that (what only holds in 1d) Hölder suffices due to only having to match the integrator Brownian Motion. This is not true. So there must (hopefully) be a different "intuitive" reason.

Comment: @Alex In Revuz-Yor in "The Case of Hölder Coefficients in Dimension One", they give some intuition on what is special about 1-d.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference and added details in your answer! I will read it after the Christmas break and come back to you. Merry Christmas!